# Solar water heater from plastic windows - what are the considerations?

Tags: solar-power, heating

I've been able to acquire several plastic-framed ("energy-saving") windows - it appears some contractor messed up the measurements and a whole batch of new custom-made windows for a nearby construction was discarded, then we managed to save quite a few before vandals got a sniff of something safe to break.

It should be quite easy to add some black-painted insulation backing, draw some black-painted pipes, and add the rest of infrastructure but will it work? How will the "energy-saving" properties of these windows affect such use - will they help keeping the inside very hot, or opposite, will they prevent IR from getting inside?

Comment: Welcome to Sustainable Living! Can you provide a bit more information? What exactly do you mean with "energy-saving windows"?

Comment: @THelper: Typical modern PVC profile framed windows with dual glass, [like this](http://www.diytrade.com/china/pd/4840119/pvc_profiles_for_windows_and_doors.html) or [this](http://zctrading.en.made-in-china.com/productimage/TqLJmjwPOlkE-2f0j00RvLaTFwPJlkE/China-PVC-Windows.html) - normal modern windows, as opposed to "antique" wooden-framed, or single glass.

Comment: short answer: no, they're more valuable as double-glazed sealed units, than as a bodged-together solar thermal thing. Maybe a greenhouse (glasshouse)?

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

Windows treated with IR blocking films will make them less efficient as a means of solar collection but double pane windows also provide better insulation than single pane windows.

[EngergyNumbers](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/users/48/energynumbers) suggestion of a greenhouse is also a good use for them. Especially if they have a UV blocking film. Several studies suggest plants are as sensitive to UV radiation humans are and blocking UV radiation can increase plant vitality.